# with cat,awk and command unable to redirect result in txt file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, aix

I am using AIX for following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat ip.txt | awk -F ' ' '{print $1,$3}' >op.txt
```

or

```
awk -F ' ' '{print $1,$3}' ip.txt > op2.txt
```

So it generating file named "oxb1du" which unknown file..
Please help me

I/P file:

```
name 1
info 21
city 28
pin  31
state 34
```

Comment: after running `awk -F ' ' '{print $1,$3}' ip.txt > op2.txt` did you try opening op2.txt? May be some other process in writing to `oxb1du` and you are seeing it at last from `ls -ltr`. Try `less op2.txt` after running the `awk` command.

Comment: yap i can see op2.txt which is blank and o/p of that awk written in oxb1du file

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example of the text that is in the ip.txt file? so we can see the format

Comment: could it be that you are trying to print from a 3rd field when you only have 2 fields?

Comment: cat ip.txt | awk -F ' ' '{print $2,$1}' >op.txt ---- corrected .. still not getting op.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the command without redirection the output in a file and observe what is happening.

As Utsaw said it is quite unlikely that this command has created the strange file.